# Pre-evaluating functions and referencing them after

Tags: list-manipulation

*Edited version

Hi all,

Suppose I have a certain function:

```
g[aa_, bb_, cc_, dd_] := 
  Sum[Sum[Sum[Sum[If[a == c + d, f[a, b, c, d], 0], 
    {d, dd}], {c, cc}], {b, bb}], {a, aa}]
```

where individual elements of `f` take a verly long time to compute.  I want to pre-compute them beforehand, and then apply their result in function `g`.  What I can use is:

```
ff = Table[f[a, b, c, d], {a, aa}, {b, bb}, {c, cc}, {d, dd}];
gnew[aa_, bb_, cc_, dd_] := 
      Sum[Sum[Sum[Sum[If[a == c + d, ff[[a, b, c, d]], 0], 
        {d, dd}], {c, cc}], {b,bb}], {a, aa}]
```

i.e take values from a table where the position the value I want in the table corresponds to input parameters of `f`.  However it is highly inefficient, as I my `If` condition renders a good portion of that table to be useless and with `f` computationally expensive I want to avoid computing these terms.  What I thought of doing was to run an initial loop collecting input indicies I would need and computing `f` at those only:

```
invals = {}

Do[Do[Do[Do[
   If[a == c + d,
    If[MemberQ[invals, {a, b, c, d}], 0, 
     invals = Append[invals, {a, b, c, d}]]
    , 0]
   , {d, dd}]
  , {c, cc}]
 , {b, bb}]
, {a, aa}]

tab = f @@@ invals;
```

The issue I have now though, is that I cannot simply relate elements of `tab` to specific `f[a, b, c, d]` that I call in function `g`.  What would be an optimal solution to this problem?

A thing to keep in mind is that the actual function `g` I have has 11 summations, not 4, calls multiple functions I want to pre-calculate most of which are time-expensive and the condition `If` is a little more complicated than that, which is why it is critical to me to pre-calculate their values, and apply them later.

I'd like to also mention that I will run this program on a server with 8 cores.  So what I'd ideally like to do, is to have separate programs (notebooks) generating these arrays and saving them to a separate files, and a separate program accessing that file and plugging it into the summation.

Thank you

Comment: This question is too vague as it now stands. Please frame it in terms of a specific example and show the Mathematica code for the example.

Comment: You are probably after memoization.  See, for example, [tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

Comment: How large are the ranges for the sums? 10 elements? 1000? larger?

Comment: The actual function has 6 inputs which define ranges of 6 of the sums, the rest are calculated as combinations of these 6 variables and the iterators of the previous sums.  The first two inputs are fixed at 20, the others I will have to play around with such that the time of computation is not unreasonable

Answer (score 1):

As @MikeLimaOscar mentioned in the comments, you could memoize the down-values of `f` for which it is non-zero.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] /; Equal[a, c + d] :=  
  f[a, b, c, d] = 1 (*replace with function definition*);
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] /; ! Equal[a, c + d] := 0;

g[aa_, bb_, cc_, dd_] := 
  Sum[Sum[Sum[Sum[f[a, b, c, d], 
    {d, dd}], {c, cc}], {b, bb}], {a, aa}]
```

**Update**

As for calculating the results in advance, taking advantage of parallelization, and saving them to a file, how about

```
Clear[possInputTab, posOfNeeded, neededInputTab, fOfList, makeRule, 
  fAssoc];
possInputTab = 
  Table[{a, b, c, d}, {a, aMin, aMax}, {b, bMin, bMax}, {c, cMin, 
    cMax}, {d, dMin, dMax}];
needValQ[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := Equal[a, c + d];
posOfNeeded = Position[possInputTab, _?needValQ];
neededInputTab = Extract[possInputTab, posOfNeeded];


fOfList[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := a + b/c*d;(*function definition here*);
makeRule = (# -> fOfList[#] &);

fAssoc = Association[
   ParallelCombine[
    makeRule /@ # &,
    neededInputTab,
    Join]
   ];

DumpSave["(*path and file name*).mx", fAssoc];
```

Then, to use the results

```
Get["(*path and file name*).mx"]
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] /; Equal[a, c + d] := Lookup[fAssoc, {{a, b, c, d}}][[1]];
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] /; ! Equal[a, c + d] := 0;
```

Comment: I can execute my task on a server with 8 cores available.  I'd like to parallelize the computation lists/arrays of values of `f[a,b,c,d]` save their results to a file, and then in a separate program use these results in the fat sum.